# CSS hover does NOT work after KEYUP function executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, keyup

I have a problem.  My script works perfectly, but I loose the CSS hover effect if I go back to the input field and delete the data inside it.  I no longer see the hover effect.

Before executing the keyup function, the hover effect works correctly, but after executing the keyup function I loose the hovering no longer works **IF I delete the data in the input**.

Can anyone see a problem or conflict and a possible solution?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#r1 input").keyup(function() { 
   if($("#r1 input").val().length > 0 ) 
     $("#r1 .bx").css("background-color", "#2F2F2F").css("color", "#FFF");
   else {if($("#r1 input").val().length == 0) 
     $("#r1 .bx").css("background-color", "#E8E8E8").css("color", "#000"); }});
});
```

My CSS:

```
#r1:hover div.bx, #r1:hover input { background-color: #A9A9A9; cursor:pointer}
```

Comment: where is you html pls? also your function works with id="r1", while your css is for id="r2"

Comment: Appreciate your help.  Could we chat?

Comment: Zeta has the answer for your situation. if that's not enough - look into on() function, that listens to live amendments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style tag (What javascript uses) always have preference over CSS rules, including :hover; you can obtain the desired effect this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#r1 input").keyup(function() { 
   if($("#r1 input").val().length > 0 ) 
     $("#r1 .bx").css("background-color", "#2F2F2F").css("color", "#FFF");
   else {
     $("#r1 .bx").removeAttr("style"); }});
});
```

Or you can do it better with classes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#r1 input").keyup(function() { 
   if($("#r1 input").val().length > 0 ) 
     $("#r1 .bx").addClass("ligth");
   else {
     $("#r1 .bx").removeClass("ligth");
}});
```

Comment: Your solution works, BUT the removeAttr or removeClass removes too much.  I loose everything, width, height, etc...

Comment: Is it possible to reinste css attributes after the removeAttr?

Comment: @Erik avoid style attributes in favor of CSS classes.  Then you won't have that kind of problem.

Comment: Yeah, better do it with CSS classes like in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

`.css()` will use inline styling to change the style of your elements. This will prevent pseudo classes like `:hover`.

Define classes and use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sX2sK/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#r1 input").keyup(function() {
   if($("#r1 input").val().length > 0 )
          $("#r1 .bx").removeClass('b').addClass('f');
   else {if($("#r1 input").val().length == 0)
      $("#r1 .bx").removeClass('f').addClass('b');; }});
});
```

```
#r1:hover div.bx, #r1:hover input { 
    background-color: #A9A9A9; cursor:pointer;
}

.f {background-color:#2f2f2f;color:#fff;}
.b {background-color:#e8e8e8;color:#000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS class may be being overridden by the presence of style information on the element itself.

Rather than directly specifying colours in your keyup, add or remove a CSS class:

```
.hasData {color:#FFF;}
```

using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#r1 input").keyup(function(ev) {
        $("#r1 .bx").toggleClass('hasData', !!$(this).val());
    });
});
```

Note that I'm using the 'this' from the event handler rather than searching the entire document again for the input element, and that the toggling is done with the second signature of [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) after coercing the value to boolean (so, true if non-empty).